# Mobx Out of bounds read: 2 - React-Native

Tags: arrays, react-native, mobx, mobx-react-lite

I am using my mobx in my React-native app.

**mobx**: "^6.6.2",
**mobx-react-lite**: "^3.4.0",

mobxStore.js

```
this.arr = [];

getArray(){
   return this.arr;
}


const temp = appState.getArray();
```

When fetching state array, I am getting this warning many times.

want to remove this multiline warning from mobx.
Thank you for further support.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error since many days and searched a lot to remove this warning and finally i found solution, Here we go.

```
const temp = appState.getArray().slice();
```

OR

```
const temp = appState.arr.slice();
```

This **slice()** function will remove it at all.